# zerodha - brokarage charge

Tags: taxes, tax-deduction, state-income-tax

i am using zerodha app for buying stock .
Today i found that charges(zerodha brokarage charge,stt,stamp duty) applied for buying stock.
please let me know is there any new rule /changes that zerodha app can deduct brokarage charge? [0.59 charges applied on buying stock]

Comment: Tax questions require information about the country as well as the State (since the state-income-tax tag has been used) and perhaps even the City where the OP resides.

Comment: Brokerages most definitely can charge for trades, that's how they earn money...

Comment: I’m voting to close this because it's a question best addressed to customer support for the specific product.